# Loaded 50+ images from document directory in UIScrollview app get crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Loaded 50+ images from document directory in UIScrollview app get the crash.Getting " Connection to assets was interrupted or assets died (with memory warnings)". Can anyone suggest best way to load these images? Thanks in advance. My code is in Objective-C.

Comment: Why do you need to load them all to memory? Can't you just load those that are being shown? Using a `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` would help with this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for displaying Images in your case would be using a UITableView or UICollectionView because they internally dequeue cells when they are no longer displayed on the screen.
.
In your case the UIScrollView does not dequeue its subviews, thus the screen contains the images all the time which consumes more amount of memory and the operating system closes (crashes) your app due to heavy memory usage.

Comment: Now, I am using UICollectionView when I have 20 to 30 images while scrolling in UICollectionView. I have received memory warning. Please suggest ASAP.

Comment: Can you please share the desired output that you want to achieve using CollectionView? (provide some screenshot of the layout you require)

Comment: One of the main reason for 'Memory Warning' might be the size of the Image. If the images are of very large size, it may take a large amount of memory. You might need to compress the images before displaying them in the collection view.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UITableView instead of UIScrollView.
But if they are very large images, it would crash when just load one image, unless it be preprocessed (resized).